# SharePoint Online Thresholds Problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

[image]

Hello, I want to add a calculated column to my list which has about 50,000 items, but this message pops up. What can I do to avoid this problem other than filtering the list? I would highly appreciate it if you could break down the answer to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[This Article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59) should help you a lot. There are different solutions explained aiming your problem. For example remove filters or grouping:

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the below articles where I have explained about the list view 5000 threshold issue and its possible solution:

- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/detailed-insight-on-the-sharepoint-5000-list-view-threshold-limit-issue/

  - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/overview-of-sharepoint-column-indexing/
  - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-indexed-column-in-sharepoint/

Here also similar issue was discussed :

[Calculated Column Filter fails when list view limit is reached](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240852/calculated-column-filter-fails-when-list-view-limit-is-reached)